# Set redux state in Reducer without Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm making app with using React Native.

Sometimes, I want to set redux's particular state in Reducer by just setting value without executing Action.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to be 'in' the reducer without executing an action.

Answer (score 5):

The paradigm of Redux is to always sent out an action for whatever change you want to incur in the application state. If you don't follow the paradigm, how about not using Redux?

Comment: I understand it. But sometimes... I want make an exception. So I want to know if it's possible. Thanks though.

Comment: Not using Redux is not an option for me because I want to use it for most case.

Comment: @BrightLee then what is the matter with actually using it? Just do it :) don't be lazy

Comment: @BrightLee by the way, you can always start off with a component state. You don't have to store everything in the redux app state.

Comment: Haha, you're right. I'm lazy. And I know that too that I can always work with component state. But it's the case that I want to set some state into redux without action.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the state without using an action/reducer. All you have to do is alter the state variable!

A quick note: You should try and generate a new state object with the desired changes instead of altering the old state object. This is in keeping with [Redux's suggested immutable update patterns](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html).

Comment: No, I read your question. I guess I'm just not understanding it. You want to change the state without passing an action to a reducer, right? You can totally do that.

Comment: According to his question he wants to update Redux state (his store), which he cannot do without firing off an action from an action creator.